# when i do calculation num1 + num 2 answer is coming num1+num2undefind on screen

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

```js
(function () {
    let screen = document.querySelector('.screen');
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    let clear = document.querySelector('.btn-clear');
    let equal = document.querySelector('.btn-equal');

    buttons.forEach(function (button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            let value = e.target.dataset.num;
            screen.value += value;
        });
    });

    equal.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (screen.value == '') {
            screen.value = "Please Enter Value";
        } else {
            let answer = eval(screen.value)
            screen.value = answer;
        }

    });

})();
```

when I do calculation `num1 + num 2` answer is coming `num1+num2undefind` on screen
but answer should be like `num1 + num 2` = answer

Comment: please include [mcve] (the html and expected output) and clarify your error as you don't have `num1` or `num2`

Comment: paste your html code

Comment: editing it while pasting html code this error comes It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. @Anilkumar